# Check whether a connection exists to a remote host using paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using single object of `paramiko.SSHClient()` for executing a command on a remote machine. When I use `ssh.exec_command(cmd)`, and the connection to remote host is lost, `ssh.exec_command` hangs up.

Is there a way to check for connection existence before `ssh.exec_command()`?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a long running SSH connection, you may want to use the [Keep Alive](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config) parameter via [Transport.set_keepalive](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html#set_keepalive).

Comment: I tried that.
I set_keepalive to 1.
Now it shud send packet at interval of 1 sec and if connection is not available , it shud know it, and then Transport.is_active() shud return false.
But strange is that, after that also , when network is not availbale, is_active() returning true. :-(

I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate possibility, maybe [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/) would work.  It wraps the command line ssh command instead, so it's definitely not the paramiko approach... just a though.